# can i use "ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso on a windows 8 laptop with an intel processor?

Tags: ati, intel

I have windows 8.1 with an Intel duo processor. 
I think AMD is a type of processor and it sounds like it might not work to me.

Answer (score 1):

Amd is the name of Intels competitor, but in this case Amd64 refers to the fact that it is suitable for 64 bit processors - both AMD AND Intel.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use it.The architecture is named after AMD because AMD invented it, with the Athlon 64. Similarly, the 32-bit i386 architecture is named after Intel's 386 processor, because it was the first of its kind, but i386 will also work on AMD processors,vice versa.